# Why vacuuming an air chamber is much slower than vacuuming an argon chamber?

Tags: vacuum, instrument

When pumping a chamber full of air down to a certain level of vacuum, it takes a while. However, when that same chamber is full with argon, reaching the same level of vacuum is much faster. What makes the two so different?

Comment: @count_to_10, yes. Does it matter?

Comment: @count_to_10 nice idea, but relative weight more important when one gas replaces another - e.g. working with liquid nitrogen people should not work in a confined space, but have plenty of ventillation as cold nitrogen gas can force air (with oxygen) up and out and there is a risk of asphixiation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The water in the air makes the difference. It coats the walls and then takes ages to pump off. For really good vacuum systems need to be baked to 100 degrees plus to drive off the water and pump it away.

So if letting up a vacuum chamger to atmosphere it is best to use argon or dry nitrogen - but be careful not to use a cylinder and overpressurize the chamber.

A nice solution I use sometimes is to have a long coiled copper tube go into liquid nitrogen - fill the chamber from that and the nitrogen vapourizes in the pipe and fills the chamber to exactly one atmosphere and no more.

Finally, this is good for quick changes inside, but if you need to leave a chamber up at atmosphere for sometime water can get in and it makes less difference to use dry gas.

Comment: from what I know, water microdrops evaporate in about 1 second. why water is an issue?

Comment: @Sparkler, non-micro drops stay liquid and gradually boil new water vapor, especially when they are wetting large surfaces like insulation blankets

Comment: @Sparkler the problem is they are not micro drops, as Martin points out, but adsorbed onto the (frequently steel) surfaces inside the chamber.

Comment: Those with lots of vacuum chamber experience know this well. Pumping down a chamber on a hot, humid August day in New Jersey can take quite a while... For a turbo-pumped system, the roughing pump will get down quickly, the turbo will kick in, and then the pressure will seemingly stall at about 2E-5 Torr for some time.  Then it finally drops through that, only to stop at 2E-6 Torr for another agonizingly long wait.  Finally it will drop to base pressure. Those are, respectively, water vapor, and adsorbed water on the chamber walls. Backfilling with dry nitrogen helps, not opening helps more!